# Laravel AWS PHP SDK - CreatePlatformEndpoint throws 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am using "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "~3.0"

When i am trying to register the android device its throwing the error.
Below is the snapshot of it.

[image]

I tried with 2 different code formats but both gives the same exception.

```
  $device = 'gcm_id_here';

  $sns = App::make('aws')->createClient('sns');
  $result = $sns->createPlatformEndpoint(['Token' => 'device_unique_id',
                                'PlatformApplicationArn' => $device]);

  // or

  $credentials = new Credentials('key', 'secret');
  $client = new SnsClient([
      'version'     => 'latest',
      'region'      => 'us-west-2',
       'credentials' => $credentials
  ]);

  $SNSEndPointData = $client->createPlatformEndpoint([
     'PlatformApplicationArn' => $device,
     'Token' => 'device_unique_id'
  ]);
```

Please help me solve this issue.